# How to setup a Gradle plugin project in IntelliJ?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to create a standalone Gradle plugin project as described in the [Gradle documentation](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html). I would like to use [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) with code completion for [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org). Since there is no specialized wizard to create a Gradle plugin project I have to do it manually.
I already managed to add the [Groovy SDK (binary)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download) in the IDE via: *File / Other Settings / Default Project Structure* as shown in the screenshot.

[image: IntelliJ / Project Structure]

To start with I created a new Gradle project which also contains the Gradle wrapper. I then create a Groovy script named `MyExamplePlugin.groovy` following the project structure of the [sdk-manager-plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin/blob/0.12.0/src/main/groovy/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/SdkManagerPlugin.groovy#L15); please note me if this project does not follow the desired setup.

```
.
├── MyExamplePlugin.iml
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── plugin
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── groovy
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── example
│           │           └── MyExamplePlugin.groovy
│           └── resources
│               └── META-INF
│                   └── gradle-plugins
│                       └── myexample.properties
└── settings.gradle
```

Then I start implementing the class:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyExamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
   // ...
}
```

The problem is that `org.gradle.api.*` cannot be found.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to a new, empty folder and type:

```
gradle init --type groovy-library
```

Then edit the generated build.gradle file and add:

```
compile gradleApi()
```

To the dependencies, and:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

To the plugins near the top.

Then run:

```
./gradlew idea
```

And open the generated project in IntelliJ

Comment: People use the 'idea' plugin a lot, does it really do anything for you? I have been working with Gradle and IntelliJ for a while - never used it. Just curious. I just run the wrapper task then open the build.gradle file with IntelliJ.

Comment: It's more of a habitual thing with me...  I found older versions of Idea to be a bit rubbish with a gradle project... Later versions seem much better though :-)

Comment: @tim_yates Nice, thank you. I also found the [documentation for `gradle init --type`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html). It would be handy if one could pass the desired **plugin and package names** so that the generated files are ready to start with. - BTW: Here is the [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439997/how-to-add-a-function-to-android-defaultconfig-with-a-gradle-plugin) if you can help.

Comment: I think instead of the gradle init task getting more complex, we should be looking at lazybones https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones and templates like this https://github.com/melix/lazybones-gradle-plugin-template

Comment: compile gradleApi() saved my day! Great advice, thanks!
Btw. apply plugin: 'idea' allows you to control or override Idea project settings and isn't required (but useful). More info [on this site](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html)

Comment: if you have already opened the project in intellij before applying the idea plugin you may have to `refresh all gradle projects` from the Gradle tool window for it to recognise the classes

Comment: gradleApi() +1 fixed autocompletion in build file.