# How to add a function to android.defaultConfig with a Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I want to create a Gradle plugin which adds functions to the [Android Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html). I want to add a `getGreeting` function to `android.defaultConfig` such as outlined here - but via a plugin:

```
// build.gradle
android {
    defaultConfig {
        def getGreeting = { name ->
            return "Hello ${name}"
        }
    }
}
```

I started preparing the Groovy project in general. Now I am at this point:

```
package com.example.myexample

import com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.StopExecutionException


class MyExamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        if (hasAndroidPlugin(project)) {
            throw new StopExecutionException(
                "Must be applied before 'android' or 'android-library' plugin.")
        }
        // def extension = project.android.extensions.create("foobar", MyExamplePlugin, project)
        // def AppPlugin androidPlugin = project.plugins.getPlugin("android")
    }

    static def hasAndroidPlugin(Project project) {
        return project.plugins.hasPlugin(AppPlugin) || 
               project.plugins.hasPlugin(LibraryPlugin)
    }

}
```

Since I never used Groovy I do not even know how to debug into the class. The commented lines might be a way to access the `android.defaultConfig` block. How can I add a function there?

Comment: I'm not sure adding a function is what you really want (or possible). What's the point of the getGreeting function? What is it used for?

Comment: @athor It is a placeholder for multiple more complex functions which I do not want to add to every *build.gradle* in every project I am working on. Therefore, I would love to put these functions into a "library".

Comment: @JJD: Were you ever able to figure this out? In my case I would like to write some String resources (using `resValue`) - I am currently doing this in `defaultConfig`, but now I want to transfer the logic to another project and so was thinking of writing a plugin...

Comment: @david.mihola No, I did not find out how to do this. But nowadays I would look into the [Gradle `buildSrc` documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) which should be helpful for extracting functionality. You can even use Kotlin instead of Groovy.

Comment: @JJD: Thanks for the reply - I think I have a solution now that's mostly working. Also, yeah, I've been converting the Gradle config of our main project to Kotlin over the weekend and it feels very nice!