# How to setup a Java Gradle plugin project in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm having issues setting up a Java Gradle Plugin project for IntelliJ.

Specifically, I can't get the Java to import the required gradle library.

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for Groovy and ported it over for Java.

Insure you have gradle downloaded, and the gradle bin directory added to your path.

Create a new directory for your project to exist in.  Open up command prompt, and run the following command:

```
gradle init --type java-library
```

Then edit the generated build.gradle file and add the following the the dependencies:

```
compile gradleApi()
```

Also and the following:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

This should result in a build.gradle that looks like:

```
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()

    // The production code uses Guava
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Then back in command prompt, run:

```
gradlew idea
```

And open the generated project in IntelliJ

Groovy Source: [How to setup a Gradle plugin project in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436365/how-to-setup-a-gradle-plugin-project-in-intellij)